# Cannot create a views for show content revision

Tags: views, 8

I got a problem when adding new view in 

Home > Administration > Structure > Views.

I insert options like this.

[image: view config]

It shows (I applied Debug mode for look Stacktrace)

```
    The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br> 
</br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException</em>: The &quot;&quot; plugin does not exist. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;doGetDefinition()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">52</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;getDefinition(NULL) (Line: 945)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\wizard\WizardPluginBase-&gt;defaultDisplayFiltersUser(Array, Object) (Line: 904)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\wizard\WizardPluginBase-&gt;defaultDisplayFilters(Array, Object) (Line: 725)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\wizard\WizardPluginBase-&gt;buildDisplayOptions(Array, Object) (Line: 699)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\wizard\WizardPluginBase-&gt;instantiateView(Array, Object) (Line: 1275)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\wizard\WizardPluginBase-&gt;validateView(Array, Object) (Line: 167)
Drupal\views_ui\ViewAddForm-&gt;validateForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator-&gt;executeValidateHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 276)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator-&gt;doValidateForm(Array, Object, &#039;view_add_form&#039;) (Line: 119)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator-&gt;validateForm(&#039;view_add_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 571)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;processForm(&#039;view_add_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 314)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;buildForm(&#039;view_add_form&#039;, Object) (Line: 74)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController-&gt;getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel-&gt;handle(Object) (Line: 19)
</pre>
```

It tell The "" plugin does not exist. Any idea to find error cause for this problem. Thanks,

---

**More information**

occur on both Drupal version 8.5.1 and 8.5.3

I saw some solution in stack exchange. It solve by install GD library. but checked in Report status. it has already installed.

[image: GD installed]

any advise solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node_revision table doesn't contain a column for type, so you can't add the content type filter here. So don't fill in a content type for now and create the View for all types. Then add a relationship to Content in the ADVANCED section. Now all node fields are available in the View and you can add a filter for the content type in FILTER CRITERIA.